# Call method using dbus-send

Tags: dbus

I've catched some d-bus method using dbus-monitor.

```
method call time=1705508504.541036 sender=:1.322 -> destination=:1.334 serial=81 path=/StatusNotifierItem; interface=org.kde.StatusNotifierItem; member=ContextMenu
```

Using GUI tool qdbusviewer, I can run this method succesfully.
But when I'm trying to use dbus-send command, I'm getting error:

```
[ntfs@ntfs-a320mh ~]$ dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply  --dest=:1.334 /StatusNotifierItem org.kde.StatusNotifierItem.ContextMenu
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.334 was not provided by any .service files
[ntfs@ntfs-a320mh ~]$
```

Destination "1.334" created dynamically, so it's really doesnt have service file in /usr/share/dbus-1/

Is there a way to call that method?

Answer (score 0):

The error message means "Such a destination doesn't exist on this bus," which is because you're trying to send the message on the wrong bus.

"StatusNotifier" looks like something inherently session-specific – not something you would ever find on the global system bus – so you need to send the call over the `--session` bus.